# Polymorphic Associations for Multiple User Roles in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I'm a designer/HTML+CSS dev learning Rails, and I'm having trouble with multiple user roles. My main models are as follows:

```
Studio
has_many :locations, dependent: :destroy
has_many :events, through: :locations
has_many :teachers, through: :events

Location 
belongs_to :studio, :class_name => Studio, :foreign_key => "studio_id"
has_many :events
has_many :teachers, through: :events

Event 
belongs_to :location, :class_name => Location, :foreign_key => "location_id"
belongs_to :studio
has_many :teachers

Teacher 
belongs_to :event, :class_name => Event, :foreign_key => "event_id"
belongs_to :location
belongs_to :studio
has_one :user, :as => :roleable
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

User
belongs_to :roleable, :polymorphic => true
```

The Teacher/User relationship is the tricky bit; I'm not sure if it should be reversed.

Users have basic profile info, Teachers have many details. All users can follow teachers, but teachers can also invite new teachers, and list other teachers as influences. I had this set up as

```
Teacher
has_many :guests, class_name: "Teacher", foreign_key: "host_id"
belongs_to :host, class_name: "Teacher"    
has_many :influences, class_name: "Teacher", foreign_key: "student_id"
belongs_to :student, class_name: "Teacher"

User
has_many :favorites, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "fan_id"
belongs_to :fan, class_name: "User"
```

Does this look right, or should I say that User has_one :teacher ? The latter seems more correct, but it made my views really difficult. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are teachers and users different models? Surely a teacher is just a user with additional permissions?

Comment: @Jon Because teachers have many more fields in their profiles, so if it's one table / STI there will be lots of empty cells, which I read was a bad thing?

Comment: How about your `User` model includes everything that is common to all users, and then if you need lots of additional data just for the special `teacher` users, then they have a `TeacherProfile` object which `belongs_to` a given user?

Comment: That's what I had, but then it was harder to get to the TeacherProfile data from Events. And a couple self joins seemed to belong in a Teachers model — though maybe I needed to put them all in the Users model, only accessible with certain permissions?

Comment: Well, an `Event` likely `has_one :teacher`. However, that teacher should be a particular `User`. As your examples show, you can set the given `class_name` for an association, so your `teacher` is really a `user`. Then your event can easily ask its teacher for whatever details it needs from that teacher's profile.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try that setup with TeacherProfiles. Large events would have multiple teachers, so I did has_many. And then I'd have two relationships of Users to Events, as teachers or as attendees.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80638/discussion-between-jon-and-erica).